# Facebook Login Token coming as Null

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, liferay-7

We are using facebook login in Liferay 7 Portal. Till now facebook login was working fine but all of sudden we have started receiving token as null because of which login functionality is not working? Does anyone have idea what could be the issue?

Comment: Facebook changes the token format between API v2.2 and v2.3. And v2.2 was deprecated last week

Comment: But we are not mentioning any version in call. By default it will point to facebook's latest sdk.

Comment: _“But we are not mentioning any version in call. By default it will point to facebook's latest sdk.”_ – first of all, an API and an SDK are different things. And the API falls back to the lowest version your app can use, if you do not specify the version explicitly.